# Discrete Random Variable; Finding Probability of X=Y

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable uniformly distributed on the integers $1,...,n$ and $Y$ on the integers $1,...,m$. Where $0 < n ≤ m$ are integers. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
What is the probability $X = Y$?

I know how to the majority of the set up, the only thing I don't get is let's say $k$ is the number that $X = k = Y$.  What is $\Pr(X=k)$ and $\Pr(Y=k)$?  We would need these to for the computation but I am not sure how to get these.

Comment: It is mentioned that the random variables are 'uniformly' distributed implying that $X$ assumes all values from $1$ to $n$ with equal probability. Similarly for $Y$ on $1$ to $m$. Can you now figure out those probabilities?

Comment: Would it be $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and $\frac{1}{m-1}$ for X and Y?

Comment: It would be $1/n$ and $1/m$ for $X$ and $Y$ respectively since there are $n$ and $m$ elements in the sets respectively.

Comment: A uniform disturbution is $\frac{1}{b-a} where a < x <b so wouldn't it be  1 < x < n?

Comment: You are confusing the discrete uniform distribution with the continuous uniform distribution. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution .

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen is correct. Another way to see this is as follows. There are $n$ possible values that $X$ can take, all with equal probability. Since their sum has to be $1$, the probability of each of them as to be $1/n$ and not $1/(n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For all $i \in \{1,\dots, n\}$ and $j \in \{1,\dots, m\}$ we have $P(X=i,Y=j) = \frac{1}{nm}$ and therefore

$$P(X=Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(X=i,Y=i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{nm} = \frac{1}{m}$$